# Error in Copy file from s3 to redshift table after unload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to unload a table from redshift cluster 1 and then copy the contents to redshift cluster 2. I am running the following commands :

```
unload ('select * from table_name') to 's3://bucket/dump_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx' delimiter '|' addquotes escape allowoverwrite;

copy cluster2_table from 's3://bucket/dump_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx' delimiter '|' removequotes escape;
```

This is running fine on most of the tables, but getting error in two of them.

The issue is that the second column is being read as the first column. Example :
[image]
[image]

I am not sure what is wrong with the file on csv. Its working fine for other tables.

Comment: Can you post the raw_field_value from stl_load_errors and the DDL for the COPY target table?

Comment: @BillWeiner The screenshot shows the raw_field value from sql_load_errors table. And the DDL for create statement for the first two columns is as follows : `Create table table_name ( key int4, load_dt timestamp, ....)`.     Hope this helps. Let me know if more info is needed

Comment: The most obvious answer is that the DDL on cluster 2 doesn't have key as the first column but rather load_dt.  Sounds like you have ruled that out.  If you post the line as text I can try to recreate the issue.

Comment: Could it be related to using double-quotes or single-quotes?

Comment: Sample `"14"|"2017-11-14 09:30:10"|"abc"|"1"|"abc"|"abc@"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"2017-11-13 17:37:34"|"2017-11-13 17:38:32"|"guest "|""|""|"US"|"smunol"|""|""|""|"abc"|"0"|"0"|"0"|""|"en"|"free"|""|"id"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"organic"|""|""|""|""|""|""|"ar"|"5.4.8.4"|""|""|""|""|""|""|"0"|""|"0"|"0"|"0"|"global"|""|""|"123"|"0"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"1"|"1"|"f"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"abc"|"control"|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|""|"f"|""|""|"f"|""|"f"|"2021-09-10 00:20:17"`

Comment: It was an issue with DDL only. Although I checked each column manually and all were identical in both the clusters. But deleting the table and re-creating it worked.

Comment: Good to hear that you got past the issue